# Issue reading HTTP request body from a JSON POST in PHP

Tags: php, json, post, http-post

I'm writing a script that is registered as an endpoint for a webhook. I know that it's successfully registered because I'm writing the header of every request to my server logs. Here's a sample:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: =={obfuscated}== 
Content-Length: 1918
```

The API that I've registered with is POST-ing a JSON object to my script, and I'd like to parse that object using PHP. As you can see from the request header, there's a nice big fat JSON object waiting to be parsed. It seems straightforward, but it hasn't been.

At first I tried using `$_POST['json']` or just `$_POST` but since the data isn't in an array, I wasn't really sure how to access it like that.

I've tried using `file_get_contents('php://input')` and `fopen('php://input', 'r')` with and without `json_decode()` but no luck. I can't use `http_get_request_body()` since the server I'm on doesn't have PECL and that's out of my control.

Are there any other ways to interact with the POST-ed JSON object that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: The content-type for the JSON body is wrong, so it might have been removed. But try [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

Comment: @mario I've seen that variable before, but wasn't sure how to use it. json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); didn't work

Comment: See the manual page. It needs to be enabled in the `php.ini` first. Also did you try with the correct MIME type yet? mod_security enabled by any chance?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array
```

where the second parameter in `json_decode` returned the object as an array.

Comment: Works for me, too. Just can't believe that JSON data is not recognized by PHP. I understand that it is raw data type after all, but still...

Comment: `$_POST` is only filled with values when receiving a request body with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` **Content-Type** header. Due to the stream nature of PHP's request body, you will either get data in `$_POST` ***or*** the input stream, not both.

Answer (score 5):

Even when the following works.

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If you want to continue using $_POST send the data as FormData

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('key', 'value');
return axios.post('url', fd)
```