# Json to PHP. Am I doing it right

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my jQuery code

```
function ajaxCall(dataStream) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'be/email.php',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataStream),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

The dataStream is `{ email: "da@gt.lo", skype: "dasd"}`.

Is this correct way of sending a json to PHP. I can see the json being sent in dev tools. But i cannot get them from my php.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Your problem is almost certainly on the PHP side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue reading HTTP request body from a JSON POST in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php)

Comment: @Lizbeth please, write console.debug(type of dataStream); console.debug(dataStream); before $.ajax(...., cause dataStream looks like a json string, but I dont kow if you are pasting an object or dictionary, probably is a bad formed json

Answer (score 3):

Change it as below:

```
data: {ds: JSON.stringify(dataStream) },
```

Then on PHP, you can get it by `$_POST['ds']`

Basically, data should be sent as `key: value` pairs

Comment: No, that's if you are sending JSON encoded data embedded in URL encoded data.

Comment: post an example so we all can see

Answer (score 2):

By using `JSON.stringify`, you are actually converting your Javascript object to a String.
Thus, it will send a string to your PHP script, and you will need to `json_decode()` it to retrieve values.

You should rather use:

```
data: dataStream
```

to send an array of values, and retrieve them with `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['skype']` in your PHP script.