# Can't send post to PHP script from nodejs and receive echo

Tags: php, node.js

[I got the following code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441786/post-to-php-from-node-js/26840793#26840793)

I've tried this code with variable `data` being equal to `'test=yes'` or with `data` being equal to `{test:'yes'}`

Here is the php script

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){ 
   error_log("inside");
   echo "and I'd also like to return this";
};
```

And here is the **nodejs** piece of code:

```
function postToPHP(data, path){

    var httpreq = require('http');
    var querystring = require("querystring");
    var data = querystring.stringify(data);

    var options = {
        host : 'localhost',
        path : 'www' + path, //path is well defined in the actual code
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length' : data.length
        }
    };

    var buffer = "";

    var reqPost = httpreq.request(options, function(res) {

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            buffer = buffer+data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
           return buffer;
        });
    });

    reqPost.write(data);
    reqPost.end();

}
```

And the call of postToPhp

```
       //treat message?
        var message = "test=yes";
        //OR
        var message = "{test:'yes'}";

        var buffer = postToPHP(message,"path");
        console.log("buffer from PHP",buffer);
```

`buffer` is undefined

Nothing is shown in the error log and I assume something is not working with the code that I can't figure so I hope someone can help me figure this one out.

Comment: Remark: `res.on('end', function() { return buffer; });`- where do you think you return here to? actually that return value will be lost currently.

Comment: Where is `postToPHP()` being executed?

Comment: You can't return a value from inside a callback function like this. Either you pass a callback to `postToPHP()`, which gets executed, when the data is received or you create a Promise from it.

Comment: @Sirko could you exemplify please? And why is the script from php not called?

Comment: Your post request seems fine. As for the other stuff have at look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1169798

Comment: @Sirko actually the callback is defined in httpreq... and the script just doesn't get called because I can't log anything...

Comment: @extremeMeta There is no callback defined to your `postToPHP()`, which is async as well ... And as I said - cant see any error in the request itself.