# Call coddeigniter controller function using nodejs socket.io

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, codeigniter, socket.io

I am new with `node Js` `socket programming`, I want to call `php function` from `nodejs socket`.

I don't know is it possible but let me know if it is possible.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var req = httpcall.request('http://your_url/controller/function/data, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
         res.on('data', function (chunk) {
         // console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);                 });
         
       });
       
       req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('error: ' , err.stack.split("\n"));
       });
```

try with http

```
var httpcall = require('http');
httpcall.createServer(function (req, res) { });
var req = httpcall.request('http://yoursite/controller/function/, function (res) {
                            res.setEncoding('utf8');});
```

Comment: thanks tushar, I tried this but I am not able to get response from php function, could you please tell me how to send response and get in node js. thanks once again..

Comment: if you are using core PHP then pass param in url and get in php file witl $_REQUEST

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441786/post-to-php-from-node-js