# JSON input is not getting the right value

Tags: php, node.js

I created Microservice and I wanted to send some object data to php server

```
{     
      _id: '5ef3018e8fbebe7395a586d2',
      name: 'Jimmy',
      user: 'Alexa',
      email: 'jimmalexa@yopmail.com',
      logintype: 'NORMAL',
}
```

when I send this above data probably it says wrong input inside postman and when I convert this to string

```
{     
      "_id": "5ef3018e8fbebe7395a586d2",
      "name": "Jimmy",
      "user": "Alexa",
      "email": "jimmalexa@yopmail.com",
      "logintype": "NORMAL",
}
```

It worked how do transform my data and send to php that can understandable

getting input in php I am doing like this :

```
$Users->insertTo(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));


var data = {     
      _id: '5ef3018e8fbebe7395a586d2',
      name: 'Jimmy',
      user: 'Alexa',
      email: 'jimmalexa@yopmail.com',
      logintype: 'NORMAL',
}
var options = {
             url: xyz.com/insert, 
             form: { input: data }
        }; 
  request.post(options, function(err,result,body){ 
    var res_data = JSON.parse(body); cb(true) 
  })
```

Comment: take a lookat this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441786/post-to-php-from-node-js

Comment: You should edit the question and add the code where you are actually building the request and sending it.

Comment: @eol updated please have a look

Comment: assume that xyz.com/insert is other website if I send data object into postman and use xyz.com/insert url it does work fine

Comment: when I use this website send via request.post from another website it does not work for me