# how to use ajax request without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

```js
function imageHandler(myToDo,myimageId)
{ 
    $.get('{{path('imageHandler')}}',
        {imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo},  
        function(response) {
            if(response.code == 100 && response.success) {
                //success
                alert(myToDo+' was sent');
            }
            else if(response.code == 200) {
                //code 200 = user not logged in
            }; 
        }, "json");
}
```

This is the working ajax code for a symfony2 application im writing.

I'm using `$.get` from jquery to send the data, how is it possible to write this function without jQuery?, I have already looked into other similar questions but I don't understand the answers.

Already tried this

```
function imageHandler(myToDo,myimageId)
{ 
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var vars = {imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo};

    hr.open("GET", "{{path('imageHandler')}}", true); 
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if(hr.code == 100 && hr.success)
      {
        //success
      }
       else if(hr.code == 200) 
       {
        //code 200 = user not logged in
       }
    } 
    hr.send(vars);  
}
```

here is the answer:

A co-worker just answered the question.
Thanks for your help, here is the answer

```
function imageHandler(myToDo,myimageId)
{ 
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xml.open("GET", "{{path('imageHandler')}}", true); 
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 

    xml.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
       var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

       if(serverResponse.code == 100 && serverResponse.success)
       {
        //success 
       }
       else if(serverResponse.code == 200) 
       {
          //not logged in

       }

        xml.send({imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo});   
   }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I already tried that, but the code doesn't respond, I would appreciate if you would check my edited question

Comment: What do you mean with *"but the code doesn't respond"*? Overall I don't think you have *really* read the documentation.

Comment: doesn't respond = button that triggers the "imagehandler" function does nothing, also the console shows no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get your HTTP verb right**

```
hr.open("GET", "{{path('imageHandler')}}", true);
```

You are making a GET request but trying to send a request with a body. You need to use POST (or maybe PUT), not GET.

```
hr.open("POST", "{{path('imageHandler')}}", true);
```

**Alternatively**: The jQuery code you wrote is making a GET request and encoding the data as a query string. You could do that instead.

---

**Send the data format you claim you are sending**

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

You say you are sending JSON but…

```
var vars = {imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo};
hr.send(vars);
```

… `vars` is a JavaScript object. When converted to a string, it will look something like `"[Object object]". If you want to send JSON, you need to make JSON.

```
var vars = {imageId: myimageId, toDo: myToDo};
hr.send(JSON.stringify(vars));
```

Note that the server side program that processes the data will need to be [set up to handle JSON requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php).

**Alternatively**: The jQuery code you wrote is sending the data encoded as a query string and not as JSON. You could do that instead.

---

**You need to check the response status correctly**

```
  if(hr.code == 100 && hr.success)
```

Where does the `code` property come from? Where does the `success` property come from? Neither of them appear in the documentation you said you read.

If you are processing the data using `onreadystatechange` then you need to test if:

- The ready state is DONE
- The HTTP Status is OK

Such:

```
if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the code and success variables are returned from a symfony2 controller like this

$response = array("code"=>200,"success"=>false);
return new Response(json_encode($response));

Comment: Then, after you've established the status of the response is OK, you need to parse the text content of the response to a JavaScript object and then run your original `if` statement on *that*, not the XHR object.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, here's something you can try:

```
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange=function() { 
    status = req.status; //this is your response.code
 responseHtml = req.responseText; }

req.open("GET","your ajax file here",true);
req.send();
```

This is just an idea about ajax request in javascript. [more info here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp).

Comment: The `responseHtml = req.responseText;` looks misplaced.

Comment: thank you for answering, your suggestion looks like the code I've already tried (<see second source code>) I would be thankful if you could compare the jquery and javascript to see why they aren't responding the same

Comment: @FelixKling: I wrote that just as an idea, thanks for correction!