# Add a dynamic numeric id when get all the element by a certain class (array) in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select a certain element inside an array in jquery, getting the class which is something like . My purpose is to edit each row and then changing them dynamically with Ajax. The first step is to select all of each row with jquery onclick.

My code is the following:

```
<?php foreach ($database as $item): ?>
<tr class="row_<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>">
<th id="id_<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $item["id"]; ?></th>
<th contentEditable="true" class="credit_type"><?php echo $item["credit_type"]; ?></th>
<th contentEditable="true" class="association_name"><?php echo $item["association_name"]; ?></th>
<th contentEditable="true" class="address"><?php echo $item["address"]; ?></th>
```

and so on which is producing the following html:

```
<tr class="row_1 odd">
                <th id="id_1">1</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="credit_type">0</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="association_name">ciao</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="address">123 cool street</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="city">Toronto</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="province">0</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="postal_code">l4n4m4</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="country">0</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_type">0</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_begin">2018</th>
                <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_months">1</th>
                <th><button class="edit" id="edit_1">Edit</button></th>
                <th><button class="edit" id="delete_1">Delete</button></th>
            </tr>
```

With jquery, I want to select all the children element of the column with the class of row_1 and do it for each row (row_2, row_3 and so on).

My jquery is pretty basic:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $( "button.edit" ).click(function() {
      var id = this.id;
      var value = $(".row_ th").text();
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'update.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { all_my_value },
    success:function(response){
        console.log('Save successfully');               
    }
});
```

My question is that if there is any way to add my dynamic value id to the row when I get all the elements with a certain class.

Comment: I need to make an update call with ajax and send all the value with php after.

Comment: Ok, I'm really unclear on what you are asking for then.  Are you saying you want to select all the ids from each of the rows?  Or just the row that the button.edit is in?  I don't see button edit in your markup to give a hint towards this.

Comment: Let me fix my code

Comment: Ok, so are you saying you want to select all the text for each column in that row?

Comment: Do you think that I could do everything in my server side code, calling the ajax function only to update my value through ajax?

Comment: Yes, that match my variable id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic puts a `data-name` on each of the columns that it should serialize.  It starts at the button clicked, goes up to the parent row, and then finds all the elements that have the data field.  It then reduces all their [data-name, innerText] pairs into the result object, and logs the data at the end for you to verify.

```js
$('button.edit').on('click', function(e){
  var $button = $(e.target);
  var $namedColumns = $button.closest('tr').find('th[data-name]');
  var data = $namedColumns.get().reduce(function(result, column){
    result[$(column).data('name')] = column.innerText;
    
    return result;
  }, {});
  
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="row_1 odd">
  <th id="id_1" data-name="id">1</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="credit_type" data-name="credit_type">0</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="association_name" data-name="association_name">ciao</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="address" data-name="address">123 cool street</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="city" data-name="city">Toronto</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="province" data-name="province">0</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="postal_code" data-name="postal_code">l4n4m4</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="country" data-name="country">0</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_type" data-name="cycle_type">0</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_begin" data-name="cycle_begin">2018</th>
  <th contenteditable="true" class="cycle_months" data-name="cycle_months">1</th>
  <th><button class="edit" id="edit_1">Edit</button></th>
  <th><button class="edit" id="delete_1">Delete</button></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It makes sense, is it possible then to create an array with this string? I'm using split, but I don't think it creates an array

Comment: What exactly do you want the array to look like?

Comment: allTheInputThs has to be split in a numeric way and I need to assign each value to a variable like first_value = allTheInputThs[0]

Comment: Are you essentially wanting to serialize this row?  Getting something like `{id:1, credit_type:0, association_name:ciao, ...}` ?

Comment: for the ajax call and then I need to send the ajax call to the method in my class, kind of complicated for me but you know, I like to try stuff

Comment: Updated the question to put all the data into an object.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Now, is there any way to sort them out and send them to an update request with jquery? If you have time could you have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256884/call-an-method-function-inside-a-class-in-object-oriented-php-with-ajax-and-up

Comment: Keys in an object are not guarenteed to be in any specific order, so sorting them isn't really an issue.  Especially since you can access them directly with the key.  If you give this object to an ajax request, that is not performing json conversion, it will put the key value pairs in the query string in the url or body, depending on GET vs POST.  In which case PHP can access them normally with $_GET['key'] or $_POST['key'].  If you send it in as actual json, that involves something different and I would suggest you...

Comment: ...read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php for more details on how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I notice the order.. but the my biggest problem is to call the function with ajax

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/  Various reading on the subject.

Comment: Yeah I got that part. My problem is that my system is kind of different, especially when it gets to the part of the actions and urls. I solved it, thank for your fantastic help. The only thing that I didn't get it is the way you code the order with reduce. Does it exist a function to avoit to sort the results?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: var data = namedColumns.get().reduce(
    function(result, column) {
      result[$(column).data('name')] = column.innerText;
      return result;
    },{}); 

Will create an array that it is sorted. I don't even quite understand how it works reduce. I looked in the documentation but your function is pretty clever.. I just want to understand what you did and why it sorted my value in an alphabetic order

Comment: It doesn't create an array.  It creates and object.  With key value pairs.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce  `result[$(column).data('name')] = column.innerText;` is putting into the result object the string key `$(column).data('name')` and assigning it the string value of `column.innerText`.  `[]` in this case does not denote an array.  It is array notation for accessing an object in this case.  `myObject.subThing` could also be written as `myObject['subThing']`

Comment: and why in alphabetical order?

Comment: I do not see anything in alphabetical order...?

Comment: I console.log the object and I obtained the following key-pair values:

address: "85 St George St"
association_name
:
"designation"
city
:
"Toponto"
country
:
"0"
credit_type
:
"0"
cycle_begin
:
"1969-12-31"
cycle_months
:
"1"
cycle_type
:
"0"
id
:
"1"
postal_code
:
"M5S 2E5"
province
:
"0"

Comment: The first key for me when I run this in chrome is the "id" key, so it's not in order.  Nothing about the logic is inherently performing an alphabetical sort.  If sorting is happening on the display or some where else then that is browser specific.  Edit: "id" is also the first key for me in firefox.  Edit: and in IE

Answer (score 0):

Get every element, and save the id to a data attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```
var id = 0;

$( ".yourclass" ).each(function( index ) {
  //start with id=1
  id++;
  $(this).attr('data-id', id);
});
```

Then you can select with the data attribute:

```
$(".yourclass[data-id='yourid']")
```

Comment: My class is called row_1, row_2

Comment: Is the class even relevant? If you want all rows with both classes you could just use 'tr'