# Send JSON object as string not array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a string that looks like this

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
```

I want to post it to a PHP file exactly in the format as seen above, not as an array. The reason is that I will later use this string somewhere else, and I have no need to implode it or reformat it.

Here is what I have now.

```
var sentdata = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}';

$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: sentdata,
    success:function(response){
    console.log('Updated'); 
    }

});
```

PHP is currently outputting this:

> Array ( [{*"name":"John",*"age":30,_"city":"New_York"}] => )

But I wanted a basic string that looks exactly like in `sentdata`.

I prefer a Jquery/JSON solution, but if I have to do something in PHP then so be it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to `JSON.stringify()` the sentdata, and set the contentType: 'json' on the request

Comment: You should receive the data just the way you sent it, post your save.php to see why the data was transformed.

Comment: I can hardly imagine where you can use json object as string though.

Comment: @Taplar `sentdata` is already a string and the correct content type is `application/json`

Comment: @Musa - all I have is $data = $_POST['data']; echo $data;

Comment: @Taplar — `sentdata`, as Musa points out, is already a string. Running it through `JSON.stringify` will double encode it which is not remotely useful.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part.  So it would just need the contentType for the request to properly put it in the body.  @Quentin

Comment: @Taplar — No. The `type` property has to be an HTTP method (like `GET` or `POST`). The `dataType` property can be `json` but it describes the expected response and sets the `Accept` header. To set the Content-Type you need to use the `contentType` property to the correct MIME type (`application/json`) as per my answer.

Comment: Mmm, actually that's only the dataType that accepts the 'json' shorthand, -_-

Comment: @Taplar You're probably thinking about `dataType` because `http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/` has nothing about `json` for `contentType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look this, notice the change to JS code

**data: {data: sentdata}**

```
var sentdata = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}';

$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {data: sentdata},
    success:function(response){
    console.log('Updated'); 
    }

});
```

Then you have string variable in PHP code:

```
$_POST["data"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the Content-Type of the request, so PHP thinks you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Since your string doesn't have an `=` in it, it treats this as a key without a value and populates `$_POST` with that data.

You need to set the Content Type request header explicitly.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    contentType: "application/json",
    // etc
```

---

**However** PHP will not automatically process JSON encoded requests. `$_POST` will be empty.

You need to parse the JSON manually as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You can still send as an object, but add the string as the value itself.

```
var sentdata = ['data' : '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'];
```

Then just access it as `$_POST["data"]`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list`

Comment: Not correct js syntax, it should be `var sentdata = {data: '...'}`