# how to post PHP codeigniter using json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, post

i'm trying to make a server side and make a rest API to post from android.
i make rest API using php codeigniter, but i don't know why i cant post using json format from mobile phone to this.
this is always get errors when i post using json format, this is my rest api code for post :

```
function post_pengajuan() {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $apd_pengajuan = $data['apd_pengajuan'];
        $list = array(
            'id_petugas' => $data['id_petugas'],
            'penanggung_jawab' => $data['penanggung_jawab'],
            'institusi' => $data['institusi'],
            'alamat' => $data['alamat'],
            'lat' => $data['lat'],
            'long' => $data['long'],
            'sifat_pengajuan' => $data['sifat_pengajuan'],
            'alasan' => $data['alasan']
        );
        $query = $this->db->insert('pengajuan', $list);
        $id_pengajuan = $this->db->insert_id();

        $x = COUNT($apd_pengajuan);
        for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
            $list[$i] = array(
                'id_pengajuan' => $id_pengajuan,
                'id_apd' =>$apd_pengajuan['id_apd'][$i],
                'jumlah' => $apd_pengajuan['jumlah'][$i]
            );
            $this->db->insert('apd_pengajuan',$list[$i]);
        }
        // $this->db->insert_batch('apd_pengajuan',$list);

        if($query) {
            $data = array(
                'status' => "success"
            );
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'status' => "error"
            );
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

when i'm post using this format, it posted :

[image: here is post using postman not json format]

but when i post using json format, it cant post. it's get error.

```
{
  "id_petugas": "14",
  "penanggung_jawab": "zhzhzhdhd",
  "institusi": "gghhj",
  "alamat": "labangka",
  "lat": null,
  "long": null,
  "sifat_pengajuan": "Urgent",
  "alasan": "hhzhzhzhs",
  "apd_pengajuan": {
    "id_apd": [
      2,
      4
    ],
    "jumlah": [
      15,
      13
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the error when post using json :

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1048</p>
        <p>Column 'id_petugas' cannot be null</p>
        <p>INSERT INTO `pengajuan` (`id_petugas`, `penanggung_jawab`, `institusi`, `alamat`, `lat`, `long`,
            `sifat_pengajuan`, `alasan`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)</p>
        <p>Filename: controllers/Api.php</p>
        <p>Line Number: 47</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

please help mee :(

Comment: `always get errors` - what errors?

Comment: @don'tpanic i've posted it. it not receive json, it get null data

Comment: the erros it too many.
but the main error is this

Comment: @Richard Kyle Are you sure you're making a `POST` request and not `GET`?

Comment: @sauhardnc yes, i'm using post in postman and using raw body and json format.

Comment: @RichardKyle can you do a quick `print_r($this->input->post());` in your `post_pengajuan` method and see if it receives anything?

Comment: @sauhardnc it dont get anything. it only null array

Comment: @sauhardnc but when i'm post using form body, it give array data with the data that i post

Comment: Yes, I think you should use, form-data instead

Comment: @sauhardnc but how if i'm post using jsonencode from mobile side?
it get errors always

Comment: Try using this - `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);`, this will convert the `form-urlencoded` value in an `associative array`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue reading HTTP request body from a JSON POST in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php)