# What is the difference between data of Ajax and body of fetch API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch, http-post

An ajax function from jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

And this is a request using a fetch API

```
const data = { name: "John", data: "Boston" };
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
    body: data,
};

const response = await fetch('/api ',options);
const responseData = await response.json();
console.log(responseData);
```

Also how come this fetch implementation is producing an error in my node terminal ?

If I use a digit instead of 'Boston' for example the Unexpected token changes to '<' .

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Is there anything I should watch out for between these two?

data of **ajax** and body of **fetch**?

(*I am not using them simultaneously the way*)

Comment: At least strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481693/how-do-i-get-fetch-to-post-data-the-same-way-as-jquery-does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) we can see that...

> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs unless the `processData` option is set to false. For example, `{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }` is converted to the string `"a=bc&d=e%2Cf"`. If the value is an array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below). For example, `{ a: [1,2] }` becomes the string `"a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2"` with the default `traditional: false` setting.

`fetch` doesn't do that. But separately, you've said you're sending JSON by including `Content-Type: application/json` as a header, but you aren't doing that (and your jQuery code doesn't do that either, it sends URI-encoded data).

You have to do it yourself. If you want to send JSON, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
};
```

If you want to send URI-encoded data, use `URLSearchParams`:

```
const data = new URLSearchParams([ // Note this is an array of
    ["name", "John"],              // [name, value] arrays
    ["data", "Boston"],
]);
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
};
```

If you want to send standard form encoding, use `FormData` (exactly like the above, but with `FormData` instead of `URLSearchParams`.

> Also how come this fetch implementation is producing an error in my node terminal ?
> If I use a digit instead of 'Boston' for example the Unexpected token changes to '<' .
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
> ```

Because your object is being coerced to a string, and it coerces to `"[object Object]"`, which is invalid JSON as of the `o`.

---

Side note: Your `fetch` code is falling prey to a footgun in the API: `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* error, not on HTTP error. You can't assume that a fulfilled promise from `fetch` means your request was successful, you have to check:

```
const response = await fetch('/api ',options);
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
}
const responseData = await response.json();
console.log(responseData);
```

Comment: What do you mean by fetch rejects its promise on *network error*?
I'm really new to working with web API and http stuff.
Also thank you so much for this side note(I should read the documentations more).

Comment: @JohnSmith - If `fetch` can't even talk to the other end defined by the URL (can't connect, or gets no response to the request, or gets back a network-level error like a failed SSL negotiation etc.), that's a network error. But if it successfully talks to the other end and the other end sends back an error via HTTP (such as 5xx [server failure], a 404, that sort of thing), `fetch` fulfills its promise with a `Response` object whose `ok` property is `false` and with the relevant HTTP status code in its `status` property.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
> ```

You **claim** you are sending JSON.

> ```
> const data = { name: "John", data: "Boston" };
>
> body: data,
> ```

`data` is an object, not JSON.

When it gets forced into a string (because it isn't a data type recognised by `fetch` so it gets converted to a string automatically) it becomes `"[object Object]"` which is still not JSON. (The `[` starts an array and then the `o` is an error).

---

If you want to send JSON, you need to convert to the object to JSON yourself. Use `JSON.stringify`.

---

Also note that while the server-side code appears to be able to handle JSON input, jQuery sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, not JSON.

So to match that you would need:

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.append("name", "John");  
searchParams.append("location", "Boston");

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             },
    body: searchParams.toString(),
};

const response = await fetch('/api ',options);
const responseData = await response.json();
console.log(responseData);
```